# fill NaN from other records in dataframe and filter unique records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have the following df:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['cus1234', 'Sara@example.com','Mexico', np.NaN],['cus1234', np.NaN ,'Mexico','348384'],['cus1234', 'Sara@example.com',np.NaN ,'348384'],['cus1234', 'Sara@example.com','Mexico', np.NaN], ['cus930', 'fernandino@example.com','US', np.NaN ], ['cus930', 'fernandino@example.com',np.NaN,'38483483'],['cus930', 'fernandino@example.com',np.NaN ,'38483483'],['cus800033132', 'dumm@example.com','US',np.NaN ],['cus800033132', 'dumm@example.com','US','300309494994']]),

                   columns=['CustomerID', 'email','Country','phone'])
```

df4:

```
     CustomerID     email               Country          phone
0   cus1234        Sara@example.com      Mexico           nan
1   cus1234           nan                Mexico         348384
2   cus1234        Sara@example.com         nan         348384
3   cus1234        Sara@example.com      Mexico          nan
4   cus930         fernandino@example.com   US           nan
5   cus930         fernandino@example.com   nan     38483483
6   cus930         fernandino@example.com   nan     38483483
7   cus800033132   dumm@example.com          US         nan
8   cus800033132   dumm@example.com          US     300309494994
```

CustomerID is repeated but customers information are not complete. I want to fill NaN if found per CustomerID and then remove the duplicated with `drop_duplicates()`

What I did so far:

```
df4.groupby(['CustomerID']).fillna(method='ffill')

df4.groupby(['CustomerID'], sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
```

But no luck, expected output:

```
CustomerID        email                 Country     phone
cus1234        Sara@example.com         Mexico     348384   
cus930         fernandino@example.com   US         38483483
cus800033132    dumm@example.com        US         300309494994
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

replace the string nan with actual NaN's:

```
df4=df4.replace('nan',float('NaN'))
```

Finally:

```
out=df4.groupby(['CustomerID']).ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates().join(df4['CustomerID'])
```

output of `out`:

```
    email                  Country      phone           CustomerID
0   Sara@example.com        Mexico      348384          cus1234
4   fernandino@example.com  US          38483483        cus930
7   dumm@example.com        US          300309494994    cus800033132
```

Comment: Thank you Anurag, the output is not accurate, the cust930 should have a different email from the input

Comment: @Mtaly updated answer...Kindly have a look **:)**